# How to predict microtask order across Promise.then chains?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, event-loop

What is the JavaScript rule that determines the output of this code?:

```js
Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => console.log("Microtask 1"))
    .then(() => console.log("Microtask 11"));

Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => console.log("Microtask 2"))
    .then(() => console.log("Microtask 22"))
```

This is the output:

```
Microtask 1
Microtask 2
Microtask 11
Microtask 22
```

But why isn't this the output?:

```
Microtask 1
Microtask 11
Microtask 2
Microtask 22
```

Comment: Unchain your Promises that will make things clearer

Comment: Why would you **need** to? It's a very, very bad idea to rely on the order of completion of promises. Separately: There are **many** previous questions on this topic.

Comment: I think the order goes: first promise first then, second promise first then, first promise second then, second promise second then.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder could you post a link to an answer explaining this? I'd also be interested to understand this.

Comment: @RockySims - [This search turns up a few](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+microtask+promise).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Your comment opened my eyes. Thank you. Promises imply time uncertainty, so my goal was pointless in practice. I'll leave the question up for my fellow rabbit holers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see the output you see because the microtask for `Microtask 11` isn't queued until the microtask for `Microtask 1` runs, at which point the microtask for `Microtask 2` is already in the queue waiting. So the order is (skipping some details; more below):

1. Queue microtask for `Microtask 1`
2. Queue microtask for `Microtask 2`
3. Task is compelete, start processing microtasks:

   1. Execute microtask queued in #1

      - Output `Microtask 1`
      - Queue microtask for `Microtask 11`
   2. Execute microtask queued in #2

      - Output `Microtask 2`
      - Queue microtask for `Microtask 21`
   3. Execute microtask queued in #3.1

      - Output `Microtask 11`
   4. Execute microtask queued in #3.2

      - Output `Microtask 21`

Thus,

```
Microtask 1
Microtask 2
Microtask 11
Microtask 21
```

---

***But***: Writing code that relies on the order of execution of disconnected promise chains / microtask sequences is asking for trouble. :-) You can only reason about it in relation to promises you **know** are already settled, and of course in the normal case, you don't know when (or even *if*) a promise will settle. Instead, if you need a specific order, connect the chains to *ensure* order.

---

Re skipped details: I sort of glossed over things in the main explanation to keep it short and clear, but for accuracy, let's look at:

```
Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => console.log("Microtask 1"))
    .then(() => console.log("Microtask 11"));
```

...just on its own, ignoring the second promise chain to keep things simple.

Here's how that code is executed (my [blog post](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/) on promise terminology may be helpful while reading the below):

1. Execute `Promise.resolve()`, creating a promise that **in this particular case** is fulfilled with the value `undefined`.
2. Execute `.then(() => console.log("Microtask 1"))`, creating a new function and calling `then` with it on the promise from Step 1. This creates and returns a new promise, and **in this particular case**, queues a microtask to call the function because the promise is already fulfilled.
3. Execute `.then(() => console.log("Microtask 11"))`, creating a new function and calling `then` with it on the promise from Step 2. That creates and returns a new promise (which we throw away in that code) and, since the promise from Step 2 is still pending, adds the function to it as a fulfillment handler.
4. The task running this code ends, so the JavaScript engine processes the microtask queue:

   1. Execute the first microtask in the queue:

      1. Call the function logging `Microtask 1`.
      2. Since the function returns `undefined`, which isn't a promise or other [thenable](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-7), the engine fulfills the promise from Step 2 with `undefined.` (If the function has returned a promise or other thenable, the promise would instead be *resolved to* the promise that was returned.)

         - That queues a microtask to call the fulfillment handler that was registered on that promise in Step 3, the one that will log `Microtask 11` when called.
   2. Execute the next microtask in the queue *(remember that we're ignoring the other promise chain in this description, so in this case the next microtask is the one logging `Microtask 11` that was just added to the queue, not the one logging `Microtask 2`)*:

      1. Call the function logging `Microtask 11`.
      2. Since the function returns `undefined`, which isn't a promise or other thenable, the engine fulfills the promise from Step 3 with `undefined.`

         - That doesn't do anything, because that promise doesn't have any fulfillment handlers registered on it.

Answer (score 1):

`"Microtask 1"` and `"Microtask 11"` are sequential under one `Promise` & the `then` callbacks `await` for the response in the first then once it is resolved then it moves on to the next `then` in the `promise chain` in the sequence.

Hence, the output you see in the order `Microtask 1, Microtask 2, Microtask 11, Microtask 22`.

But if you do you chain all the promises you will see the expected output i.e `Microtask 1, Microtask 11, Microtask 2, Microtask 22`.:

```js
Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => console.log("Microtask 1"))
    .then(() => console.log("Microtask 11"))
    .then(() => console.log("Microtask 2"))
    .then(() => console.log("Microtask 22"))
```

NOTE: `then callbacks` (and `awaits`) are executed after the synchronous JavaScript code and in order.

Comment: "the `then` callbacks `await` for the response in the first `then` once it is resolved, then it moves on to the next then" Thank you. Drawing attention to the underlying `then` callbacks array helped me. I was confused about the JS order of operations, and felt like there must be a "pre-queue queue", and that turned out to be the `then` callbacks array. I also appreciated the connection to `await`.